# Well-defineness/existence of an integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am reading on [page 2](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/%7Epms/files/26.1/Article/26.1.12.pdf), it says

> For a finite Borel measure $m$ on the real line $\mathbb{R}$, let us recall that its Cauchy transform $G_m$ is defined by
> $$
> G_m(z)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{1}{z-x}\mathrm{d}m(x),\qquad \textrm{for } z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:\Im z\neq 0\}
> $$

**Question**: How to justify if this integral is well-defined (in case when $m$ is complex)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\int|\frac 1 {z-x}| d|m|(x) \leq \frac 1 {|\Im z|} |m|(\mathbb R) <\infty$. [All you have to know is that any bounded measurable function is integrable w.r.t. any complex measure].

Comment: Could you please explain why $|z-x|\geq |\Im z|$ holds?

Comment: $|a+ib| \geq |b|$ for any real numbers  $a$ and  $b$. Write $z-x$ as $a+ib$. What is $b$? @James

Comment: Ah ... Didn't think like that before. Here are $a=\Re z - x$ while $b=\Im z$. Thank you

Comment: I do not know if it's okay to ask you here; would you be interested to read my "project" to give feedback?